# Locating Source of Migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have a project that just started using EF Migrations.

There is an initial migration and an additional, hand-edited migration that defines indexed views.  There is no other migration.

I recently added a single property to one class.  When I create a new schema, the property is created.  However, I cannot see why it is created, since the property is not mentioned in any migration.

If I search the entire source code folder (with subfolders, *.*) for any mention of that property name, it does not appear in any EF migration code (it only appears in the class where it is defined, and in a few lines of code where the property is accessed).

When I set a breakpoint at the beginning and end of the Up() method for the two existing migrations, I can see that the table is created without the additional property by the initial migration (verified in SSMS), and that the property does not yet exist at the end of the last Up() migration.  Sometime after control leaves the last migration, some code creates a column in the database for this additional property.

To try and track this down, I hand-edited this new property into the initial migration.  Now, after the Up() method for the last migration exits, I get an SqlException

> Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'MyNewProperty' in table 'dbo.MyTable' is specified more than once.

in the constructor for my DbContext.

The stack trace only shows the code that is instantiating DbContext.

How can I track down where this additional migration is coming from?

Comment: Are automatic migrations enabled? In the `Migrations` folder you should have a `Configuration` class, have a look in the constructor for `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled`.

Comment: @Lukazoid: Yes, automatic migrations are enabled.

Comment: That would be the source of the new column then, automatic migrations mean Entity Framework will automatically map any new properties on your domain entities to SQL columns.

Comment: @Lukazoid: That does not explain why it tries to create the property after I hand-edit the property into the initial migration, and create a brand-new schema.  That is what I would actually prefer to do anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not explicitly adding a code-based migration for this new property (using add-migration), but a column is being created it can be determined that [automatic migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj554735.aspx) are enabled.

Automatic migrations allow Entity Framework to automatically determine the schema changes required to represent any changes made to the domain model, this is what is adding your new column.

You are also wondering why it still tries to add the new column even after you hand edit a code-based migration to add this new column; for each code-based migration there is a generated code-behind file (.Designer.cs) which contains a `string IMigrationMetadata.Target` property, this returns a string snapshot of what the domain model will look like after this migration has been applied.

When you edit the migration file by hand, this `Target` property still returns the old string representation of the domain, which does not contain your new property; as a result of this, automatic migrations then attempts to add a duplicate column.

The solution to this is to add your new property to the domain then use the `add-migration` command to add a new code-based migration for this new property.